# How to assign a unique color to each group of data points in a scatter3Dplot?

Tags: r

I'm new to R and working on a shiny web app. This project is based on the visualization of moving patterns of animals present in a herd. Here is a part of the data:

| collarid | latitude | longitude | height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cattle12 | 15.67 | 11.1 | 302.9 |
| cattle12 | 15.01 | 10.8 | 300 |
| cattle17 | 14.9 | 11.8 | 280.8 |
| cattle19 | 15.5 | 11.2 | 267.8 |
| cattle17 | 15.07 | 11.91 | 301.6 |
| cattle19 | 15.0 | 10.19 | 234.9 |
| cattle12 | 15.67 | 11.1 | 302.9 |
| cattle13 | 15.5 | 11.2 | 200.1 |
| cattle13 | 15.47 | 11.6 | 382.9 |
| cattle14 | 15.17 | 11.5 | 303.9 |
| cattle14 | 15.27 | 11.6 | 304.9 |
| cattle15 | 15.37 | 11.9 | 305.9 |
| cattle15 | 15.47 | 11.0 | 306.9 |

I'm using R Studio and Postgresql for the database. I want to make a 3D scatter plot to show the longitude, latitude, and elevation of each animal present in the herd. For this purpose, I have to group the data points appearing on the graph based on their collar IDs. Each animal has a unique collar ID and for each collar ID, multiple records exist in the database. My code is given below. Unfortunately, this code outputs an empty cube with no points. Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

```
    library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(plyr)
library("scatterplot3d")
library(rgl)
#Code for 3D Scatter Plot
collarid <- c("cattle12", "cattle12", "cattle17","cattle19", "cattle17", 
"cattle19", "cattle12", "cattle13","cattle13", "cattle14", "cattle14", 
"cattle15", "cattle15" )
longitude <- c(11.1, 11.2, 11.3, 11.4, 11.5, 11.6, 11.7, 11.8, 11.9, 12.0, 
12.1, 12.2, 12.3)
latitude<-c(15.67, 15.7, 15.8, 15.9, 16.0, 16.1, 16.2, 16.3, 16.4, 16.5, 
16.6, 16.7, 16.8)
height<-c(302.9, 301.6, 300.5, 303.2, 304.8, 305.8, 302.1, 310.8, 375.6, 
200.9, 234.5, 216.7, 211.8)
df <- data.frame(collarid, latitude, longitude, height)
df_uniq <- unique(df$collarid)
x<-length(df_uniq)
scatterplot3d(df$longitude,df$latitude,df$height,pch=20, color=rainbow(x) 
[df$collarid])
```

Comment: Keep in mind the *minimal* part of the [mcve] guidance. If the question is just about plotting your dataset, it's better to separate tasks and just give us the data (or a sample of it) that you're trying to plot. Setting up database drivers and connecting to them can be its own debugging project—better for us and you to hone in on the actual task in question

Comment: I have added a sample of the data to the question.

Comment: Hi Amna, please include the data in the form of code, something like `imported_data <- data.frame()`. This way people trying to answer your question can actually run your code.

Comment: I have included the data in the code now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super familiar with this `scatterplot3d` library, so there might be a more elegant solution. But the code below seems to do the trick.

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(plyr)
library("scatterplot3d")
library(rgl)
#Code for 3D Scatter Plot
collarid <- c("cattle12", "cattle12", "cattle17","cattle19", "cattle17", 
              "cattle19", "cattle12", "cattle13","cattle13", "cattle14", "cattle14", 
              "cattle15", "cattle15" )
longitude <- c(11.1, 11.2, 11.3, 11.4, 11.5, 11.6, 11.7, 11.8, 11.9, 12.0, 
               12.1, 12.2, 12.3)
latitude<-c(15.67, 15.7, 15.8, 15.9, 16.0, 16.1, 16.2, 16.3, 16.4, 16.5, 
            16.6, 16.7, 16.8)
height<-c(302.9, 301.6, 300.5, 303.2, 304.8, 305.8, 302.1, 310.8, 375.6, 
          200.9, 234.5, 216.7, 211.8)
df <- data.frame(collarid, latitude, longitude, height)
df_uniq <- unique(df$collarid)
x<-length(df_uniq)

# Create a color column by merging a df of colors and cattle ids
df <- df %>% merge(data.frame(collarid = df_uniq, color = rainbow(x)),
             by = "collarid")

scatterplot3d(df$longitude,df$latitude,df$height,pch=20, color=df$color)
```